# Kafka Connect API and Avro Object (SourceRecord vs org.apache.avro.Schema)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I have problem with sending Avro object (instance of org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord) to kafka topic with usage of kafka source connector (need to prepare SourceRecord instance).
In my case I assume that basing on schema for example:

```
{
    "namespace": "com.model.avro.generated",
    "type": "record",
    "name": " MessageExVal",
    "version": "1",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "messageSource",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "messageSourceVersion",
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

with help of `avro-maven-plugin` for maven I will generate model of classes used in my project.
Instance of class `MessageExVal` provides me “`org.apache.avro.Schema`”(by methods `getSchema() or getClassSchema()`). From second side kafka connect api requires from me `org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Schema` to be able to create new instance of `SourceRecord` returned by `poll()` method of source connector.
In configuration I am providing parameters:

```
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
```

In code of `AvroConverter` in method `fromConnectData()` executed after “poll” method, I see that conversion from `org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Schema` to `org.apache.avro.Schema` will be done. So is there any option to pass avro schema without conversion it first to "connect version", because later it is anyway converted back to avro ?
Below you can find implementation of poll method with commented point in code which I am referring:

```
@Override
    public List<SourceRecord> poll() throws InterruptedException {
        List<SourceRecord> records = new LinkedList<SourceRecord>();
        MessageExVal myValue = MessageExVal.newBuilder()
                .setMessageType(“some value”)
                .setMessageSource(“some other value”)
                .build();
        SourceRecord sr = new SourceRecord(null, null,
                "test_topic",
                myValue.getSchema(), //incorrect - different types
                myValue);
        records.add(sr);
        return records;
    }
```

Summarize everything, my question is how to put "myValue" into topic with usage of kafka connect SourceConnector? I will be very grateful for every tip :)

Comment: You shouldn't be using Avro within Connect framework. Connect has its own Schema and Struct classes

Answer (score 0):

> because later it is anyway converted back to avro ?

The data is stored in binary within the topic,so you'll still have to pay a deserialization cost

> kafka connect api requires from me org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Schema to be able to create new instance of SourceRecord

Yup. You can use `toConnectData` to get that, or you can just remove Avro from the dependencies of your code and create Schema and Struct instances from Connect directly.

The converters are responsible for serialization, and Avro is not required in Connect

Comment: Thnk you for reply ! :) 
I understand that I can create "source" data other way, by creating schema in connector by kafka schema,  but I have decided to keep avro schemas in separate project wchich i am including into other my projects.

Comment: Lets assume that we have 2 source connectors and 1 producer writing to thesame topic. When I have in one place models of objects used by my 3 separate applications (connectors and producer),  I can handle syntax consistency of messages. Thats the reason that I am preparing "avro" object in "connect" part of code (here pool() method) in similar way I will do this in producer and second connector. 
Is my approach wrong? Is there other better way to handle data syntax consistency?

Comment: I would write a utility in your Avro project that calls `AvroData.toConnectSchema`